# Disable AJAX/Javascript popup after AJAX invokes PHP function

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Ok so im using AJAX to invoke a php function everything works perfectly except that when the function is completed an empty popup window appears at the top of my page saying "xyz.com says" with an empty box and ok button. I just want it to complete with no popup and append one string to a `<P>` tag.

[image: ScreenShot]

Here is my Javascript:

```
function buildFunction() {
            document.getElementById("package").innerHTML = "Initializing Powershell...</br>";
            document.getElementById("package").innerHTML += "Building...<br><br>";

            $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'build.php',
                    success: function(data) {
                        document.getElementById("package").innerHTML += "Build Complete!";

                    }
                });
        }
```

build.php

```
function buildPackage()
{
    $serverName = "\\\\server";
    $msiName = '"""""""""MSI"""""""""';
    $installDir = '"""""""""D:\\APP"""""""""';

    $runCMD2 = "start powershell.exe psexec -accepteula -windowstyle hidden -s -i 2 " . $serverName . " cmd /c D:\app.hta " . $msiName . " " . $installDir;

    $execCMD = shell_exec("$runCMD2");
    //Begin Building
    echo $execCMD;
}

echo buildPackage();
```

Comment: are you sure you don't have a random `alert()` somewhere in your javascript code when you call `function buildFunction()`?

Comment: 100% sure would it cache if i did at one point?

Comment: Are you creating some attended installer or something? Anyway look for `alert()` in your _D:\app.hta_

Comment: there isnt one at all in the hta...

Comment: @Viney I have a feeling that because im using ```echo``` that its creating the box because if I add for instance ```echo "Build Complete";``` into the function it appears in that same box

Comment: In your chrome or firefox browser press `F12` and check the network tab for all javascript resources that are loaded. In one of these files there has to be either an `alert()` command or, if a library like e.g. bootstrap is used, you should also search for `modal` etc.

Comment: @digijay thats interesting you mention that because where I wanted the text to appear in was a modal box but as I mentioned in my answer removing echo and replacing it with return stopped the popup from happening...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what I ended up doing/figuring out was that the `echo` statements in my php were creating the pop up! Changing `echo` => `return` stopped the pop up.

```
function buildPackage()
{
    $serverName = "\\\\server";
    $msiName = '"""""""""MSI"""""""""';
    $installDir = '"""""""""D:\\APP"""""""""';

    $runCMD2 = "start powershell.exe psexec -accepteula -windowstyle hidden -s -i 2 " . $serverName . " cmd /c D:\app.hta " . $msiName . " " . $installDir;

    $execCMD = shell_exec("$runCMD2");
    //Begin Building
    return $execCMD;
}

return buildPackage();
```